# Cross-Browser-Testing in xUnit with Selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, cross-browser, xunit

I'd like to run my unit tests on different browsers with Selenium and xUnit. I couldn't find a proper solution throughout my research. I have found some variants with nUnit but they don't fit my needs.

- https://blog.testproject.io/2017/02/09/cross-browser-testing-selenium-webdriver/
- [Cross-Browser testing with Selenium WebDriver using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595354/cross-browser-testing-with-selenium-webdriver-using-c-sharp)

The soulution should execute all tests in three different browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox). Also the amount of browsers should be customizable.

Is there any proper solution?

Comment: Try to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480545/run-selenium-tests-in-multiple-browsers-with-c-sharp

Comment: @Kiksen This solution is with nUnit but I'm trying to find one with xUnit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution which doesn't actually execute the tests in multiple browsers at the same time, but it works when you execute the project manually and get the Driver Type dynamically:

```
switch (Configuration["DriverType"])
            {
                case "firefox":
                    var firefoxService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "geckodriver.exe");
                    firefoxService.FirefoxBinaryPath = Configuration["FirefoxPath"];

                    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();

                    firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", Configuration["DownloadPath"]);
                    firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
                    firefoxOptions.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream");

                    Driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxService, firefoxOptions);

                    break;

                case "chrome":
                    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                    chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", true);

                    Driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), chromeOptions);

                    break;
            }
```

I use a PowerShell script to run the .dll and write the Driver Type to the appsettings.json File via that script. Example:

```
$file = Get-Content "appsettings.json" -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$file.DriverType = "chrome"
```

Answer (score 1):

Right Now there is not perfect method to do this but you should try Watin.core Package.
This package will support IE and firefox browser and if you want to execute the test in chrome browser then you are out of luck using Watin.core package.